# PHP CI - Passing a variable from MY_controller to a method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to declare the title variable in MY_Controller in the $data variable, to use it when I load the page so I do that:

```
function __construct()
    {
     parent::__construct();

    $this->data['siteNamePrefix'] = "Mysite.com - ";

     }
```

So when I loa my page in the method of a normale controller,

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view('home',$this->data);
}
```

I don't see in the var_dump the variable siteNamePrefix that I declared in MY_controller

Comment: Try var_dump($this->data) instead of $data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `__construct()` at the top of your post is `MY_Controller::__construct()`, you have correctly extended it.

In the object instance, you just need to be using `$this` in the dump as well as in the `load()` method that follows it:

```
public function index()
{
    // $this->data should be defined here and correctly initialized
    var_dump($this->data);
    $this->load->view('home',$this->data);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so now I can't use $data['title']='tile'; for instance in my method? When I do, it doesn't appear on the dump

Comment: @cam Same problem.  `$data` is an object property.  `$this->data['title'] = 'title'`